# Merging two sorted arrays with for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, array-merge

I have a function that merges two sorted arrays into one and returns a pointer to it. I want to use a for loop rather than a while. However in some test cases the last 1 or 2 elements of the merge array are not in their place. I would appreciate if someone can help solve this problem keeping the for loop.

```
int * mergeSort(int arr1[], int arr2[],int len)
{

  /* len is the combined length of the two arrays */

    static int sorted[100];

    int pos1=0, pos2=0;

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if (arr1[pos1]<=arr2[pos2])
        {
            sorted[i]=arr1[pos1];
            pos1++;
        }
        else
        {
            sorted[i]=arr2[pos2];
            pos2++;
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: How do you handle going past the end of the input arrays?

Comment: I dont get why i need to check going past the end. Can you give an example with 2 arrays where I would go past it ?

Comment: Sure. `[1,2,3], [101,102,103]`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't seem to handle going past the end of the input arrays. If there is uninitialized memory - you get undefined behaviour.

You can avoid this by terminating your arrays with a sentinel value, for example `INT_MAX`, which should always be bigger than all possible values in the arrays:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 104, INT_MAX};
int b[] = { 101, 102, 105, INT_MAX};

int* ptr = mergeSort(a,b,6);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    cout << i << " " << ptr[i] << endl;
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gxE8KXPnx1hCY2ol)

Or you can pass the actual lengths of both arrays and handle them correctly:

```
int * mergeSort(int arr1[], int len1, int arr2[],int len2)
{

  /* len is the combined length of the two arrays */

    static int sorted[100];

    int pos1=0, pos2=0;

    for (int i=0; i< len1 + len2; i++)
    {
        if ((pos2 == len2) || (arr1[pos1] <= arr2[pos2] && (pos1 < len1)))
        {
            sorted[i]=arr1[pos1];
            pos1++;
        }
        else
        {
            sorted[i]=arr2[pos2];
            pos2++;
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5CoJzugsoOwcPVaU)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question of what's wrong with your code, but to answer the question of how to merge two sorted ranges I would suggest [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge):

```
    int * mergeSort(int arr1[], int arr2[], int len1, int len2)
    {
        //I am not condoning the use of a static buffer here,
        //I would probably use a std::vector or std::array,
        //possibly a boost::static_vector if really necessary
        static int sorted[100];
        std::merge(arr1, arr1 + len1, arr2, arr2 + len2, sorted);
        return sorted;
    }
```

I also changed `int len` to `int len1, int len2` because you need to know the lengths of the individual arrays, not just their combined length, to avoid reading past the end of the input arrays.